# Spring Boot Gradle application "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, google-app-engine, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I have Spring boot Gradle project that runs perfectly local by Gradle, but not throw the jar file created.

The project has two targets: update data at Postgres DB from another api by scheduling, and let users get the data.

Application class:

[image]

I tried to deploy my project on Heroku, Google cloud and via java -jar command,  I'm getting the same behavior.

I don't know if it's the problem but on the cloud the build runs successfuly, and after that I get the error: Error: Could not find or load main class com.Application . and ofcourse all the get requests gets denied and server is not accepts any requests.

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'application'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id "com.heroku.sdk.heroku-gradle" version "2.0.0"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

mainClassName = 'com.Application'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']

springBoot{
    mainClass = "com.Application"
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    all*.exclude group: "ch.qos.logback"
    all*.exclude module: "log4j-over-slf4j" // allow using log4j 2.x
    all*.exclude module: "slf4j-simple"     // log4j is the configured backend
}
    dependencies {
        implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.14.3'
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        implementation('org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.0.0')


        implementation('com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java:0.16')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
        runtimeOnly('org.postgresql:postgresql')
        implementation ( 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
        annotationProcessor ( 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    }

task cleanBuildPublish{
build.mustRunAfter clean
}

group 'com'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

jar {
    enabled =false
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.Application',
        )
    }
}

bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.Application',
        )
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my project structure :

[image]

the error I get on google cloud:

[image]

Comment: how did you check that it runs locally? Did you run the shaded jar or did you just run it via gradle? Also might want to add what service you are deploying to and how.

Comment: @somethingsomething I Update useful information to the question: Im still getting the same behavior via java -jar command when I ran the jar file created -> that means that something wrong with my jar file, is that mean that something wrong with my build. gradle?                                                                                                             my service update data to Postgres DB from another api by scheduling, and let users get the data.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.